# Extra character after pasting yank text into command line

Tags: vimscript, cut-copy-paste, register

I have a line of vimscript in my buffer like:

```
call MyFooFunction(1,2)
```

and I'm trying to execute it quickly.

So, I yank it (`yy`), invoke the command line (`:`), and paste it in with `<C-r>"`

But, after I paste, I see an extra *^M* at the end:

```
:call MyFooFunction(1,2)^M
```

What is this extra *^M* character and how do I not have it included when I paste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That extra character is a newline.  `yy` copies both the contents of the line and the line break.  To copy a line without the line break, you can do `0y$`.  `0` moves to the beginning of the line, and `y$` yanks until the last character of the line.  If you want to, you could map it to make it faster:

```
nnoremap Y 0y$
```

`Y` is a synonym for `yy` by default, so it is okay to map over it.  You can map it to whatever key you prefer though.